# Ошибка передачи данных bundle

Tags: java, android

В моём `RecyclerView` есть `item` по нажатию на который у меня открывается `Fragment` в нём есть `TextView`, мне нужно что бы он отображал данные взятые из `bundle`, в свою очередь `bundle` будет брать данные из БД. Но при открытии фрагмента приложение крашиться с ошибкой

```
2021-03-27 14:19:33.907 20869-20869/com.example.des E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.des, PID: 20869
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.des.Menu.Tasks.FragmentTasksBlanc.onViewCreated(FragmentTasksBlanc.java:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
```

Мой `onBindViewHolder` из `Adapter`

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterTasks.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemTasks currentItem = itemTasks.get(position);

        holder.tv_item_tasks.setText(currentItem.getTitleTasks());

        holder.cv_item_tasks.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            FragmentTasksBlanc fragment = new FragmentTasksBlanc();

            itemClickTasks.onItemClickTasks(holder.getAdapterPosition());

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TitleTasks", currentItem.getTitleTasks());
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        });

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(currentItem.getImageTasks())
                .into(holder.iv_item_tasks);
    }
```

`Fragment` который крашит приложение

```
public class FragmentTasksBlanc extends Fragment {

    TextView tv_tasks_title;

    public static FragmentTasksBlanc newInstance() {
        return new FragmentTasksBlanc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_blanc, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        tv_tasks_title = requireView().findViewById(R.id.tv_tasks_title);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        tv_tasks_title.setText(bundle.getString("TitleTasks"));

    }
}
```

Создание фрагмента

```
    private void replaceFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
        tr.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        tr.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        curFragment = fragment;
    }
```

Переход по нажатию с помощью `interface`, находиться в `MainActivity`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClickTasks(int position) {this.showFragment(FragmentTasksBlanc.newInstance());}
```

Сам `interface`

```
public interface ItemClickTasks {
    void onItemClickTasks(int position);
}
```

Comment: эта ошибка говорит о том, что в конкретном инстансе фрагмента который вы показываете arguments = null (т.е. не вызван setArguments перед выполнением FragmentTrasaction). покажите код, где вы непосредственно показываете фрагмент (в представленном коде этого нет, фрагмент просто создается но не показывается)

Comment: @Battlevisek Обновил вопрос, создание происходит с помощью `newInstance()`, но клик из `interface`

Comment: добавил ответ, посмотрите

Answer (score 2):

Нужно устанавливать аргументы именно у того экземпляра класса `FragmentTasksBlanc`, который вы потом показываете с помощью `FragmentTransaction`. Для этого вы можете например поменять код в интерфейсе на следующий, чтобы в метод интерфейса передавалась нужная вам строка:

```
@Override
public void onItemClickTasks(String titleTasks) {
    FragmentTasksBlanc fragment = new FragmentTasksBlanc();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("TitleTasks", titleTasks);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Тогда код в `onBindViewHolder` поменяется на следующий. Здесь мы просто вызываем метод `onItemClickTasks` интерфейса и передаем туда строку, содержащую заголовок.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterTasks.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemTasks currentItem = itemTasks.get(position);

        holder.tv_item_tasks.setText(currentItem.getTitleTasks());

        holder.cv_item_tasks.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
           
            itemClickTasks.onItemClickTasks(currentItem.getTitleTasks());

           
        });

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(currentItem.getImageTasks())
                .into(holder.iv_item_tasks);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте код фрагмента

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_blanc, container, false);
    tv_tasks_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tasks_title);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    tv_tasks_title.setText(bundle.getString("TitleTasks"));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: попробовал поменять, появилась такая ошибка - `Process: com.example.des, PID: 14127
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.des.Menu.Tasks.FragmentTasksBlanc.onCreateView(FragmentTasksBlanc.java:38)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)`

Comment: @Buldog, значит bundle пустой

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том что `setArguments` нужно применять на тот `Fragment` на который переходишь, но так как у меня `replace Fragment` находиться в `MainActivity`, при переходе `bundle` оставался пустым. Решение оказалось простым хотя не знаю насколько правильным, т.к. `Fragment` в `MainActivity` пришлось сделать `static`

Было

```
public Fragment curFragment;
```

Стало

```
public static Fragment curFragment;
```

И в `Adapter` указывал таким образом

```
MainActivity.curFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: Нет, это не чистое решение. У вас в интерфейс `onItemClickTasks` передаётся позиция, которую вы там никак не используете, а могли бы, но я не вижу код активности. Вместо позиции вы можете передать искомую строку или уже подготовленный бандл и прикрепить его к фрагменту уже на месте, но обычно аргументы передают в `newInstance()` и уже там создают, наполняют и прикрепляют бандл - это исключает шанс путаницы с именами ключей, которые делают константами в фрагменте